# How to solve a pow equation?

Tags: mathematics

I have an formula that generates a number from  20 to 180 (degree).

```
var a = 20 * Math.pow(str/dist, 1.5));
    a = Math.max(180, w);
```

Using this formulae, i can generates some arcs and draw them just fine and depending on `dist` (which is cursor distance from target), the arc is either very wide, or narrow (pow basicly makes it so the arc expands non-linear).

This approach works in one direction: Having a location, and a distant point, to create arc.
I need a counter-equation that gives me the required DIST for a given angle.

i.e. 
assuming `str` is 800, what is the value of `dist` so `a` would be 114 (or 68 or anything).

```
114 = Math.pow(900/dist, 1.5)) // ????
```

How can i solve this equation for dist ?

thanks,

Comment: Generally, the easiest and fastest way to find answers to similar questions is to feed it to wolframalpha.com e.g. `a = (x/y)^1.5 solve for y` gives you `y = x/a^(2/3)`. Using similar software is also less prone to errors than doing it manually on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to disregard your `max` line for a moment (did you mean `min`? Written with a `max`, any values in the 20-180 range you described will come out as 180, since `max` returns the greatest argument)

We can solve this step by step by reversing each operation. Starting with the multiplication by 20:

$$
\begin{align}
                      a &= 20 \times{(\frac{str}{dist})}^{1.5} \\
                   \frac a {20} &= {(\frac{str}{dist})}^{1.5}
\end{align}
$$

The opposite operation of a power is a corresponding root. So to undo a square \$ x^2 \$ we'd take a square root \$ \sqrt {x^2} = x \$, often available as its own function, `sqrt()`. For less common roots, we can use `pow` as its own inverse, using the fact that the `n`th root of `x`, \$ \sqrt[n]{x} \$, is just `x` to the power of `1/n`:

$$
\begin{align}
                  \frac a {20} &= {(\frac{str}{dist})}^{1.5} \\
       {(\frac a {20})}^{\frac 1 {1.5}} &= \frac {str} {dist}
\end{align}
$$

And taking the reciprocal to get \$dist\$ on top (which is the same as negating the power), then multiplying both sides by \$str\$...

$$
\begin{align}
      {(\frac a {20})}^{-\frac 1 {1.5}} &= \frac {dist} {str} \\
    str \times {(\frac a {20})}^{-\frac 1 {1.5} } &= dist
\end{align}
$$

Or in code:

```
dist = str * pow(a / 20.0, -1/1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks. The max was a typo. I didnt know how to reverse the pow, that was basicly what i was asking. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also just for the record, in your personal opinion, would this question be better served to the Math SO, even though it includes code in this specific q ?

Comment: I think it's fine to ask about math we need for games here. We'll tend to approach things a little differently in game math than in pure math (eg. using `Math`/`Mathf` libraries instead of Matlab or R code, avoiding transcendental functions whenever we can). I might recommend the math or computer science exchanges if someone had an obscure algorithm question, outside the daily experience of most gamedevs, or if they wanted proofs & explanations of why a particular formula works. It's just about which set of experts can answer the question. If we can, then it's less hassle than migrating!